# Keras ImageDataGenerator with additional columns from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a Pandas dataframe with several columns, one of which is the name of the image file.
I can use `tf.keras.ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_dataframe()`, example here:
[image: Sample DataFrame]

Apart from the image and the target, how do I get the **other data columns** like sex, age_approx, anatom_site_challenge, dignosis, etc. `flow_from_dataframe` does not seem to cover it, and I have tried TF Data options, but I would like something simpler cause it seems like such a common use-case.

Comment: What do you mean by **get** the other columns?

Comment: @DwijMehta I mean that the generator should include age_approx and sex and others while also getting the true image array for each example. So the generator will generate `(input, label)` where `input` is `[image, patient_id, sex, age_approx, anatom_site_general_challenge]` and `label` is `[diagnosis, target]`. But the `image` is not the name in the column, it's the true image located on the disk.

Comment: This [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#passing_data_to_multi-input_multi-output_models) might be able to help you.

Comment: How do you want to map it and use it?. If you have multiple target values you can use `y_col` as a list of columns.

Comment: @Tfer3 I have multiple X columns. One of those X columns is the image path, so it should be loaded into an image, the others should be kept as the metadata columns they are.

Comment: @Animesh Sinha, Currently I don't think there is any direct implementation using Tensorflow. But you can do a workaround by reading all the Images using `flow_from_dataframe` and then converting the image to a flattened array to fit in each row of a new dataframe along with other required information for the given image.